# Does ajaxify work locally?

Tags: jquery, ajax, ajaxify

Does Ajaxify only work live? That is to say, doesn't it work locally? I’m working on a local site, have a basic implementation and it hasn't changed anything.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, **Ajaxify** can work locally also. It is simply a library which is based on jQuery.

Please check all these points in your code:

1. You need to replace the URLs from where you are sending the request.
2. You need to check if you have internet access (Not sure but may be it is using any external library too).
3. You need to add the [jQuery library](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js) at the above of this library.

Here is more for [Ajaxify](https://github.com/arvgta/ajaxify).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. All those points are covered but still no fade... Using animsition in the meantime but would ideally want Ajaxify because animsition doesn't preserve the current page, only animates to the next one... One thing-- what do you mean by "replace URLs"? Thanks so much for the assistance.

Comment: Thanks. All those points are covered but still no fade... Using animsition in the meantime but would ideally want Ajaxify because animsition doesn't preserve the current page, only animates to the next one... One thing-- what do you mean by "replace URLs"? Thanks so much for the assistance.